# RenderBox was not laid out: RenderConstrainedBox#358ca relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE

Tags: android, flutter

I am  creating an app which is requires to shows analogue clock at the top left.

here is my code

```
import 'package:analog_clock/analog_clock.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';



class MyApps extends StatefulWidget {
@override
_MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApps> {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) => MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.green[900],
            title: Text('CLOCK'),
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.green,
        body: Padding(padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:10),
        child: AnalogClock(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(width: 3.0, color: Colors.black),
                color: Colors.black,
                shape: BoxShape.circle),
            width: 200.0,
            isLive: true,
            hourHandColor: Colors.white,
            minuteHandColor: Colors.white,
            showSecondHand: true,
            numberColor: Colors.white,
            showNumbers: true,
            textScaleFactor: 1.5,
            showTicks: true,
            showDigitalClock: true,
            digitalClockColor: Colors.white,
            datetime: DateTime(2020, 8, 4, 9, 11, 0),
            ),
        ),
    
    )
    );
}
```

i want to make clock at the top left . I used padding but it wasn't helpful
and it gives me this error

**Error:**

```
RenderBox was not laid out: RenderConstrainedBox#358ca relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-PAINT NEEDS-COMPOSITING-BITS-UPDATE
'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart':
Failed assertion: line 1940 pos 12: 'hasSize'
```

Here is the main.dart file where i call MyApps

**Main.dart**

```
import 'package:attendance_system_app/clock.dart';

import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());  //it run our flutter app

}
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return MyAppState();
  }
}

class MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // return MaterialApp(home: Text('Hello!'),);

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Auth',
      theme: ThemeData(
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
      ),
      home: MyApps(),
     
      
    );
  }
}
```

I want clock at this position

[image]

Please help if someone knows.

Comment: Hi There. Your code seems incomplete. Where are you using your `MyApps` widget ?

Comment: in main.dart file

Comment: Yes, could you update your question with that code as well. Since the code you have provided works perfectly by itself.

Comment: @NisanthReddy i update the questions, could u please check it now

Comment: Hi, I have posted an answer explaining why it is happening, check it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AnalogClock` by default takes all the available space of the parents and since widget `Padding` doesn't provide any constraints to it's children, The `AnalogClock` will be taking up all the height and width.

Now since you have given `width: 200`, the `AnalogClick` applied a tight constraint horizontally, but still it takes the entire height of the parent. Then, since it needs to scale itself down to 1:1 ratio of height and width, it is appearing in the middle like that.

Just add `height: 200,` to your clock and this will be the output.

[image]